# Why does my event handler cause an "is not a function" error, but works from the Firebug console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery 1.2.6, testing from Firefox 3 and IE7.  I have a very basic bit of JavaScript to reload a captcha image.  In my JS file, I have:

```
var Captcha = {
    count: 0,

    Refresh: function(){
        // Concatenate "count" to force a URL change, which forces the browser to reload the image
        $('#Captcha').attr('src', 'Captcha.aspx?' + Captcha.count);
        Captcha.count++;
    }
}
```

My link looks as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ChangeCaptcha" onclick="Captcha.Refresh();">Try a different image</a>
```

When I click on the link, I get a JavaScript error.  From the Firebug plugin for Firefox, it says "Captcha.Refresh" is not a function.  So, I go to my Firebug console in the same window, and type

```
Captcha
```

And I get an "object" in the response line (as expected).  I then type

```
Captcah.Refresh
```

And I get a function() in the response line (as expected).  I then type

```
Captcha.Refresh()
```

And it executes the function, updates my captcha image, everything is dandy.  If I go back and try the link again, it still does not work.  If I type in Capcha.Refresh() into the console without ever hitting the link, it also works fine.  What on earth am I missing here?  Clearly the JS is getting loaded, but why doesn't that function call work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem arises because you have an element with an id of `Captcha`, and a global variable with the same name. IE traditionally introduces a global variable for every id attribute. FF doesn't... but pretends it does in certain situations for compatibility with IE. In this case, the `click` handler sees Captcha as an element rather than your object.

#### Work-arounds:

Change the id of the `Captcha` element.

Or, change the name of your global object to something other than `Captcha`.

Or, use [Pim Jager's technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533817/jquery-is-not-a-function-error-but-works-from-firebug-console/533830#533830) to move interpretation of the handler into a context where the global Captcha variable has been overwritten with your own.

Or, change your `onclick` attribute to:

```
onclick="window.Captcha.Refresh();"
```

...this will force lookup of the `Captcha` property in the context where it has been replaced by your global variable.

(all of these tested in IE6 and FF3 - i recommend Pim Jager's answer)

Answer (score 7):

Try sepperating the HTML and javascript:

```
$('#ChangeCaptcha').click(Captcha.Refresh);
```

Comment: Thanks Pim - gave you an upvote for short and to the point, though gave Shog9 the 'answer' because he explained *why*