# Firefox says this is not a function. Must be a simple bug, but I can not see it

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

All the other browsers operate just fine with this, but firefox says 'share is not a function'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function share(){
        var url = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://google.com";
        var win = window.open(url, "share", "status = 1, height = 500, width = 600, resizable = 0" );
        var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
            if (win.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                window.location = "http://gmail.com";
            }
        }, 200);

    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="sharebox">
    <img id="share" src="img/share.png" onclick="share();" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested this function in FireFox 3.6.8 and it is working fine, maybe some other code is causing this problem can you submit the whole code

Comment: Looking more closely at firefox's error. It reports the error as being on line 1. Which is the doc type. Is there anything wrong with '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'

Comment: Where are you *calling* the function?

Comment: here --> <img id="share" src="img/share.png" onclick="share();" />

Comment: Sorry but this is not enough information, it is hard to figure out what is the problem. please give more code so we can help you.

Comment: posted the source. Hope someone can see a mistake... I am beginning to think its a bug in firefox

Comment: See: [Why does my event handler cause an "is not a function" error, but works from the Firebug console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533817/why-does-my-event-handler-cause-an-is-not-a-function-error-but-works-from-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. You are not allowed an object with the same id as a function name. I never knew that :s

Comment: the Id of the image is same as the function name. that's why it is not working, it is nice to know about it in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information this will be impossible to solve, but you may find that the javascript file this function is in had an error, so the parsing stops, then this function also wouldn't be parsed if it is after the part with an error.

Some browsers are more forgiving than others are on errors.

If you use JSLint (http://jslint.com/) to fix the errors that it reports, it may fix your problem.

Otherwise try to use the [firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) to see where the error may be.